# Auto-Publish updates don't show up in FB feeds?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fan-page

Since the last big changes to Facebook (addition of ticker):

The auto-publish to fan page does work. It DOES publish to my fan page. But it never seems to show up in people's feeds. I can tell this because of the amount of impressions FB shows me each posting gets.

Then, when I take the same link and organically post the blog link on my fan page, it goes into people's feeds and then impressions are normal. So its obviously only happening when the auto-publish occurs.

Comment: Could you show how you are auto-publishing with the graph api, please?